# How to export data from a Mongodb View

Tags: mongodb, view

I try hard to build stages in Mongodb, to make it faster, I try to convert this view into a collection.
I also try to export data from that view and intent to import back to another declared collection, but I cannot found any way to do that.
I try to use NoSQL Booster, but the Export function only export 100 rows and it run like crazy without ending.
Please help to export data from my view, or copy data from view to another collection
thanks

Comment: It all depends on how your view is created. I would suggest that you put up your database and view definitions in order that people can help you with it.

Comment: Are using [db.createView](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/) to create your MongoDB view?

Comment: @JoseMar, I create view by using Aggregation stages in MongoDB Compass

Comment: @OTZ, I use MongoDB Compass, in the Aggregation, I save the pipelines as with 'Create a view' option

Comment: could you post your code? I think it could be the lack of index if there is a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Just install mongoDB compass there you will have option to export any collection in JSON format.